# Float 2 elements side by side inside a container div

Tags: html, css, web

This is supposed to be an easy task, but I've been looking at it for the last 30 minutes and couldn't figure it out.

Here is the html code;

```
<div style="width: 250px;">
  <img style="float: left; width: 20px;" src="public/_images/ok_kutu.jpg" alt="kutu" /> 
  <h3 style="float: left; width: 50px; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px;">Jobs</h3>
  <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

All i want is keeping the img and h3 items side by side.
Instead I'm getting this;

[image]

Comment: You have to remove the default margin on the `<h3>` - add `margin: 0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `<h3>` elements have a top and bottom margin. You should remove them using `margin: 0`:

```
<div style="width: 250px;">
    <img style="float: left; width: 20px;" src="public/_images/ok_kutu.jpg" alt="kutu" /> 
    <h3 style="float: left; width: 50px; color: #FFF; font-size: 18px;margin:0">Jobs</h3>
    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Also, maybe look into using external CSS, rather than placing all of your style information inline. It will be much easier to maintain in the long run...

Please see this [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bH6R7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Instead of:

```
float: left;
```

And everything will work out :)

Here's the demo (change the image): http://jsfiddle.net/JjTfy/2/

P.S - You should really use separate CSS stylesheets instead of inline styling.

Comment: That's because H3 has margin. If you remove it, the vertical margin is still alright

Comment: Yeah, but if you remove the margin on `h3`, there's no need to use `inline-block` display...

Comment: Find the differences: [floating](http://jsfiddle.net/bH6R7/2/) vs [inline-block](http://jsfiddle.net/bH6R7/3/)

Comment: Using inline-block is just more flexible